# Java print on Windows XP generating big spool file

Tags: java, printing, windows-xp

I'm working on custom printing module for our application. Printging with code below on windows 7 is working well. When I've got 8pages tiff file, it generates 12MB spool. But when I execute this code on windows XP it generates spool with size something about 300MB and printing takes long time.

Please can somebody tell me how can I speed it up, or is there some workaround for this?

thanks

```
public class TIFFPrintPage implements Printable {

private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

private RenderedImage page;

public TIFFPrintPage(RenderedImage page) {
    this.page = page;
}

@Override
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
    if (page != null) {
        // convert to a BufferedImage since I cannot write a RenderedImage for some reason
        BufferedImage good = new BufferedImage(page.getWidth(), page.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2dtemp = (Graphics2D) smaller.getGraphics();
        g2dtemp.drawRenderedImage(page, new AffineTransform());
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
        g2d.drawImage(smaller, 0, 0, smaller.getWidth(), smaller.getHeight(), null);
        g2d.dispose();
        good.flush();
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    } else {
        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PrinterException {
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printerJob.setPrintService(service);

    PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();

    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setSize(595.275591, 841.889764); // width, height A4 format
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
    pf.setPaper(paper);

    SeekableStream s = new FileSeekableStream("c:/test3.tiff");
    TIFFDecodeParam param = null;
    ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", s, param);

    Book book = new Book();
    for (int i = 0; i < dec.getNumPages(); i++) {
        book.append(new TIFFPrintPage(dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(i)), pf);
    }

    printerJob.setPageable(book);

    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(Sides.DUPLEX);

    printerJob.print(pras);

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using TIFF files?

Comment: because I'm using multipage files.